# How to show the license overview in GitHub?

Tags: github

[image]

but when I add the same LICENSE to my repo no overview is shown.

[image]

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use GitHub's built in way of adding a license, either when you [create a repo](https://github.com/new) or through [adding a new file](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-license-to-a-repository/), it adds the overview/preview as well.
[image]

I don't know of a way to add the overview when you upload your own license file (not through GitHub's way of adding a license).

Answer (score 0):

The [license overview in GitHub](https://github.com/blog/2252-license-now-displayed-on-repository-overview) is only displayed if GitHub can recognize your license. To recognize licenses, GitHub relies on the open source project [Licensee](https://github.com/benbalter/licensee). Common reasons for unrecognized licenses include:

1. **The license is not in its own file.** The license text needs to be, in full, in its own file, preferably `LICENSE` or `LICENSE.md`. The name of the license is insufficient, as is the full content in the `README.md`.
2. **You made an addendum to the license text.** Licensee expects a near-perfect match to the original license text (rf. [choosealicense.com](https://choosealicense.com/)). Any additional title or footnote will prevent recognition.
3. **Licensee does not support your license.** Licensee only recognizes licenses registered on [choosealicense.com](https://choosealicense.com/). The code behind this website is open source and [new licenses can be submitted](https://github.com/github/choosealicense.com/blob/gh-pages/CONTRIBUTING.md#adding-a-license).